# Why is alpha set to 15 in NLTK - VADER?

Tags: nltk, vader

I am trying to understand what the VADER does for analysis of sentences. 
Why is the hyper-parameter Alpha set to 15 here? I understand that the it is unstable when left unbound, but why 15?

```
def normalize(score, alpha=15):
"""
Normalize the score to be between -1 and 1 using an alpha that
approximates the max expected value
"""
norm_score = score/math.sqrt((score*score) + alpha)
return norm_score
```

Answer (score 0):

Vader's normalization equation is  [image]  which is the equation for [image]

I have read the paper of the research for Vader from here:http://comp.social.gatech.edu/papers/icwsm14.vader.hutto.pdf

Unfortunately, I could not find any reason why such a formula and 15 as the value for alpha was chosen but the experiments and the graph show that as x grows which is the sum of sentiments' scores grow the value becomes closer to -1 or 1 which indicates that as number of words grow the score tends more towards -1 or 1. Which means that Vader works better with short documents or tweets compared to long documents.